# angularjs create text from selectedRoomList

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs. I want to create text from selectedRoomList. I have json data. I am using nested ng-repeat to display the data in spinner. If I change the value I have to display the selectedRoomList in text form for ex, if I selected two rooms in single and one room in double it needs to display 2SGL,1DBL it's little bit tricky for me, please some one help me to solve this problem.

```
"roomTypes" : [{
        "type" : "Deluxe",
        "Deluxe" : [{
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Deluxe",
                "roomCategory" : "Single",
                "maxOccupancy" : 2,
                "childAllowed" : true,      
                "number" : 0
        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Deluxe",
                "roomCategory" : "Double",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Deluxe",
                "roomCategory" : "Triple",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Deluxe",
                "roomCategory" : "Twin",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        }]
},
{
        "type" : "Superior",
        "Superior" : [{
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Superior",
                "roomCategory" : "Single",
                "maxOccupancy" : 2,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Superior",
                "roomCategory" : "Double",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Superior",
                "roomCategory" : "Triple",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        },
        {
                "id" : "",
                "name": "Superior",
                "roomCategory" : "Twin",
                "maxOccupancy" : 3,
                "childAllowed" : true,
                "number" : 0        

        }]
}]
```

I have ng-repeat in following html code, which will display the different room type like:

```
header :Deluxe: 
label : Single  spinner : value :number 

<div ng-repeat="room in roomTypes">
    <h5 style="color:#ff7043;">{{::$eval('messages.webapp.itinerary.hotel.roomType.'+room.type.toUpperCase())}}</h5>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="roomCat in room[room.type]">
            <label class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">{{::$eval('messages.webapp.itinerary.hotel.changeRoom.'+roomCat.roomCategory.toUpperCase())}}</label>
            <div touch-spin ng-model="roomCat.number"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I write logic to make a text like 2SGL,1DBL
below is my function,

```
$scope.getMultipleRoomList = function(multiple){
    var multipleRoom=multiple;
    var numSignle;
    var room='';
    console.log('Hello Welcome To',numSignle);
    multipleRoom.forEach(function(item,idx){
        var roomType=item;
        roomType[item.type].forEach(function(item1,idx1){

            if(item1.number!=0){
                console.log(numSingle);
                if(item1.roomCategory.toUpperCase()=='SINGLE'){
                    room=room+item1.number+'SGL,';
                }
                else if(item1.roomCategory.toUpperCase()=='DOUBLE'){
                    room=room+item1.number+'DBL,';
                }
                else if(item1.roomCategory.toUpperCase()=='TRIPLE'){
                    room=room+item1.number+'TRPL,';
                }
                else if(item1.roomCategory.toUpperCase()=='TWIN'){
                    room=room+item1.number+'TWN,';
                }
            }
        });

    });
    room = room.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
    return room;
};
```

The above function called whenever the reference changed in the spinner,
and also then var numSingle will throw error if use that variable inside forEach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but something like that should work:

```
var categoryLabels = {
  single: 'SGL',
  double: 'DBL',
  triple: 'TRPL',
  twin: 'TWN'
}

$scope.getMultipleRoomList = function (roomTypes) {
  var roomLabels = [];
  roomTypes.forEach(function (roomType) {
    roomType[roomType.type].forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.number > 0) {
        roomLabels.push(item.number + categoryLabels[item.roomCategory.toLowerCase()])
      }
    });
  });
  return roomLabels.join(', ');
};
```

`numSingle` probably throws an error because you misspelled it `numSignle`

Comment: Thank you so much. i will try and update if i got any errors

Comment: yeah it's working fine. but one think missed. it's my mistake i can't able to tell my problem clearly. because my english is not good. i will try to overcome that.

Comment: the above problem i want RoomType wise for example: RoomType is standard i choose one single , and two double in standar. and then in two single and one double in Deluxe RoomType so my result is

Comment: 3SGL, 3DBL and also roomtype wise. Standard : 1SGL,2DBL Deluxe: 2SGL,1DBL .

Comment: total room and roomtype wise also , anyway thank you so much for your help